Angular 16 Universal not rendering on server and keep showing the static version
`I created an Angular 16 SSR application. It works great and I can navigate between different components without any issue on the User Interface.
The only thing I really want to fix is that in the page source (html content view), I keep seeing the static page and not the dynamic page information.
Can someone help me identify the issue?
import 'zone.js/node';

const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const helmet = require('helmet');
let win;
try {
  const template = fs.readFileSync('dist/socialBlasterMarketing/browser/index.html').toString();
  // TODO: fix
  // win = domino.createWindow(template);
  // global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error creating window with Domino:', error);
}

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as compression from 'compression';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/socialBlasterMarketing/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule
  }));

  // Enable compression middleware
  server.use(compression());

  server.disable('x-powered-by');
  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  server.use(helmet.hsts({maxAge: 5184000, includeSubDomains: true, preload: true})); // Set HSTS - Strict to use HTTPS only for next 60 days

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`URL: ${req.url}`);
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.url }] }, (err: any, html: any) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
        return;
      }

      if (html.includes('<div id="not-found"></div>')) {
        res.status(404);
      }

      res.send(html);
    });
  });


  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';


angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "socialBlasterMarketing": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/socialBlasterMarketing/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/sitemap.xml",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {"replace": "src/environments/environment.ts", "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"}
              ],
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "700kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "700kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "socialBlasterMarketing:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "socialBlasterMarketing:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "socialBlasterMarketing:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/robots.txt",
              "src/sitemap.xml",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/socialBlasterMarketing/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "socialBlasterMarketing:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "socialBlasterMarketing:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "socialBlasterMarketing:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "socialBlasterMarketing:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "socialBlasterMarketing:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "socialBlasterMarketing:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "socialBlasterMarketing:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "socialBlasterMarketing:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

tsconfig.server.json
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/server",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "server.ts"
  ]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "social-blaster-marketing",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.13.1",
    "npm": "10.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "postinstall": "ng build && ng run socialBlasterMarketing:server:production",
    "start": "node dist/socialBlasterMarketing/server/main.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build",
    "startserver": "node server.js",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run socialBlasterMarketing:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/socialBlasterMarketing/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run socialBlasterMarketing:server",
    "prerender": "ng run socialBlasterMarketing:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^16.2.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "domino": "^2.1.6",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "helmet": "^7.1.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^19.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/compression": "^1.7.5",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}

I've failed to find a working solution for angular 16 SSR online`

Do you have initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking' option set when importing the router module in app-routing.module.ts?  Should be added anyway when running ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
